# Vue.js - Loading alternative component when dynamic variable does not exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've been struggling with this for a few days and was hoping for a graceful way of handling dynamic URLs with no data.

I have the following routes:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/product/:slug', component: Product},

    {path: '/404', component: PageNotFound, alias: '*'}
  ]
});
```

In the `Product` component, I have an object of products and, depending on the `slug` variable, load the product to show.

The issue i'm having is when the URL is a slug that does not exist in the products dataset. I would like to load the `PageNotFound` component, without updating the URL.

Is this possible? It would be nice to have a consistent 404 page throughout the app and would also be good for me not to have to repeat myself with a `v-if` in the product table.

The closest I've got to it is this:

```
if(!product) {
    this.$router.replace({path: '/404', query: {product: this.$route.params.slug}});
}
```

However, this updates the actual URL which is not very good UX.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kyle pointing me in the right direction, this is what I came up with.

---

Becuase I am being slightly unorthodox and using server-side components and JavaScript, I already had my page not found component loaded - which looks like this:

```
const PageNotFound = {
  name: 'PageNotFound',

  template: `<div>
    <h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
    <p>Head back to the <router-link to="/">home page</router-link> and start again.</p>
  </div>`
};
```

I made sure the `PageNotFound.js` file was loaded in the HTML before my product component, so I was able to do the following:

```
const ProductPage = {
  name: 'ProductPage',

  template: `<div>
    <div v-if="product"><h1>{{ product.title }}</h1></div>
    <page-not-found v-if="notFound"></page-not-found>
  </div>`,

  components: {
    PageNotFound
  },

  data() {
    return {
      notFound: false
    }
  },

  computed: {
    product() {
      let product;

      if(Object.keys(this.$store.state.products).length) {
        product = this.$store.state.products[this.$route.params.slug];

        if(!product) {
          this.notFound = true;
        }
      }

      return product;
    }
  }
};
```

Things to note in the above:

- Data is being loaded asynchronously, hence the check to see if products exist
- The PageNotFound component is loaded in - this is ES6 for `PageNotFound: PageNotFound` - Vue then automatically makes a `<page-not-found></page-not-found>` element
- That element then has a v-if which gets triggered. As the first container would not be in existence if there is no product, only the 404 component is displayed
- I don't do it based on product, as you would get a flash of the 404 if the product data was still loading via an API.
- It's better practice to have the URL params as `props` ([see docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html)), which I will be doing at some point!

To conclude, this allows you to show a consistent 404 page throughout your SPA (single page application) while maintaining URLs with dynamic routes. It allows you to load another component or show another component without updating the URL and also lets you have a wildcard 404 for dynamic routes.

Hope that all makes sense and helps someone in the future and saves them from wasting ~4 hours of trial, error and googling. (and yes I have "keyword" and phrase stuffed this answer to help someone find it...)

Comment: Hey mikestreety, one other thing to say: I'm not sure if you're utilizing this library from inside of another application, or if it's entirely Vue.js, but I recommend not trying to emulate the same idea of functional components that the React community encourages. They're different situations here. Consider following the official Vue.js style guide going forward - it will likely make your life easier: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/

Comment: Sorry, Kyle. I'm not quite sure what you mean? It seems Vue does have functional components - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.5 or is this not what you mean? Thanks for your help!

Comment: For you to utilize that, you need to be establishing in the Vue api that `functional: true`. As it stands, you're receiving no performance boost and losing on syntactic clarity. Additionally, you also have computed and data present in the product component, meaning it is not stateless. Unless your component is stateless, it cannot and should not be functional. I highly recommend you stick to the typical and officially-recommended structure of `template, script, style` tags in a single .Vue file. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components

Comment: Thanks again Kyle, I'll have a read. Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to be able to use command line compiler for this particular project

Answer (score 3):

You could conditionally render your PageNotFound component in `Product.vue` if the query returns no results, and then not have to fiddle with your router at all.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle! That sounds perfect. How would I go about loading a component within a component?

Comment: Inside your `<script>` you'll import the component file, and then you'll have the ability to render it in your template! More on this here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/call-a-component-from-another-component

Comment: Thanks for your help Kyle! Have posted an answer with what I did in the end.